# javascript onclick event not working c# asp.net 4.0

Tags: c#, asp.net

Dynamic Hyperlink click event is not working in c# asp.net. Do any one can help me on this

```
                HyperLink h1 = new HyperLink();
                h1.NavigateUrl = "javascript:void(0)";
                h1.Attributes.Add("onclick", "edit(" + rd[0].ToString() + "," +                    rd["column1"].ToString() + "," + rd["column2"].ToString() + "," + Convert.ToString(rd["existance"]) + "," + rd[4].ToString() + "," + Convert.ToString(deldate) + "," + rd["modifier"].ToString() + ")");
                h1.Text = "Edit";
                Table1.Rows[rw].Cells[7].Controls.Add(h1);
                h1 = new HyperLink();
                h1.NavigateUrl = "rulesuploading.aspx?type=D&id=" + rd[0].ToString();
                h1.Text = " | Delete";
                Table1.Rows[rw].Cells[7].Controls.Add(h1);
```

//Javascript

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" Runat="Server">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function edit(id, col1, col2, ex, ef, del, mod) {
            document.getElementById('id').value = id;
            document.getElementById('coltxt1').value = col1;
            document.getElementById('coltxt2').value = col2;
            document.getElementById('extxt').value = ex;
            document.getElementById('efftxt').value = eff;
            document.getElementById('deltxt').value = del;
            document.getElementById('modtxt').value = mod;
        }

</script>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: You should post the HTML source to the elements you're referencing with all those document.getElementById calls.

Comment: What is the error on your browser console ?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to view your source on the web page so you can see if your event is well attached and if your call "edit" has the same signature with the edit function in your script tag.

Answer (score 0):

I guess one semicolen missing at the end.

```
 h1.Attributes.Add("onclick", "edit(" + rd[0].ToString() + "," +                      rd["column1"].ToString() + "," + rd["column2"].ToString() + "," +  Convert.ToString(rd["existance"]) + "," + rd[4].ToString() + "," + Convert.ToString(deldate) +  "," + rd["modifier"].ToString() + ");");
```